# How to clear SQL Server data cache on SQL Server RDS instance?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

I'm trying to tune the performance of some queries.  Normally, I'd execute the following statement in between query executions to make sure I'm starting fresh, with no data pages being cached:

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
```

Unfortunately, RDS doesn't give us access to anyone in the "sysadmin" role, so I can't execute that statement.  I get the following error message:

```
User 'myuser' does not have permission to run DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS.
```

Is there another way to force my queries to run as if they were running for the first time, without using any cached data?

EDIT: I should be clear, I'm not using a stored procedure, I'm just executing ad-hoc queries in SSMS to test an approach to solving a problem.  I don't think this has to do with re-compiling a stored procedure.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  No, I don't believe there is a solution.

Answer (score -1):

When a procedure is compiled for the first time or recompiled, the procedure’s query plan is optimized for the current state of the database and its objects. If a database undergoes significant changes to its data or structure, recompiling a procedure updates and optimizes the procedure’s query plan for those changes. This can improve the procedure’s processing performance.

There are times when procedure recompilation must be forced and other times when it occurs automatically. Automatic recompiling occurs whenever SQL Server is restarted. It also occurs if an underlying table referenced by the procedure has undergone physical design changes.

Another reason to force a procedure to recompile is to counteract the "parameter sniffing" behavior of procedure compilation. When SQL Server executes procedures, any parameter values that are used by the procedure when it compiles are included as part of generating the query plan. If these values represent the typical ones with which the procedure is subsequently called, then the procedure benefits from the query plan every time that it compiles and executes. If parameter values on the procedure are frequently atypical, forcing a recompile of the procedure and a new plan based on different parameter values can improve performance.

SQL Server features statement-level recompilation of procedures. When SQL Server recompiles stored procedures, only the statement that caused the recompilation is compiled, instead of the complete procedure.

If certain queries in a procedure regularly use atypical or temporary values, procedure performance can be improved by using the RECOMPILE query hint inside those queries. Since only the queries using the query hint will be recompiled instead of the complete procedure, SQL Server's statement-level recompilation behavior is mimicked. But in addition to using the procedure's current parameter values, the RECOMPILE query hint also uses the values of any local variables inside the stored procedure when you compile the statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspProcedure @Param1 varchar(30)
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT 1
```

[Doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190439.aspx)
You can also use with select statement only

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspProcedure @Param1 varchar(30)
    AS
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SELECT 1 FROM tblName OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: I'm not using a stored procedure.  I'm fairly confident that my problem is that SQL Server is caching data, not my code.

Comment: @KOTJMF no problem you can use with `SELECT` statement which i mentioned in my answer

Comment: humble request for **downvoter** please leave comment so i can improve my answer or learn whats wrong

Comment: I just tried adding "OPTION (RECOMPILE)" to my select statement, and the query returns very quickly, so this is not addressing my root problem, which is that I can't get SQL Server to stop caching the data.

Comment: @KOTJMF `RECOMPILE` uses for removing cache plan

Comment: Right, and caching the execution plan is not the problem in this case.  Caching the data is the problem.  I don't know how to be any more clear about this.

Comment: @KOTJMF **Query results are not cached** The compiled execution plan will be cached 
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9380

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92431/discussion-between-kotjmf-and-tinka).